# Вызвано исключение: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException" в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll. Как исправить

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

существует контекст CommonContext и класс SapmleData в котором происходит инициализация бд. После context.savechanges вылетает исключение.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:
>
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Невозможно
>   вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице "users",
>   когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF.

```
public class SampleData
{
    public static void Initialize(CommonContext context)
    {
        if (!context.users.Any())
        {
            context.users.AddRange(
                new User
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Gregory"
                },
                new User
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Elena"
                },
                new User
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Mikhail"
                }
                );
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class CommonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }

    public CommonContext(DbContextOptions<CommonContext> options) 
        : base (options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: В заголовке вопроса Вы указали тип исключения. Это чудесно. У исключения, кроме типа, есть еще текст сообщения, где описывается, что произошло. Добавьте этот текст в вопрос.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице "users", когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Я примерно это и подозревал.)*

Поле `Id` в таблице `User` - автоинкрементное. Сервер сам присвоит ему уникальное значение во время вставки записей.

```
        context.users.AddRange(
            new User
            {
                Name = "Gregory"
            },
            new User
            {
                Name = "Elena"
            },
            new User
            {
                Name = "Mikhail"
            }
        );
```

Comment: Буквально за 2 минуты до того как вы ответили, до самого дошло. В любом случае, спасибо)